# Help with SQL multi-table query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I hoping someone can help me with a MySQL query.

I am trying to create a query in a MySQL database that finds all rows that matches a string 'foo' in column_1 of Table_A and then searches those rows with 'foo' and for all values of 'bar' in column_2 of Table_A returns all rows in Table_b that contain 'bar' in column_8.

My starting query is:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A WHERE column_1 LIKE 'foo';
```

The above query only finds all data that matches a string 'foo' in column_1 of Table_A. What code do I need to add to take the above results and use Table_A column_2 to search for matches in column_8 of Table_B? I can't seem to figure out how to perform this query.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: Your request doesn't make any sense.  Is there a relationship between `Table_A` and `Table_B`?  As explained you don't even need `Table_A`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not clear from your description if this is right but it sounds like you're looking for a [JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    TABLE_A a
  INNER JOIN TABLE_B b 
  ON a.column_2 = b.column_8
 WHERE 
    a.column_1 LIKE 'foo'
     and a.column_2 = 'bar'
```

Comment: Thank you! Seriously, thanks for taking the time to read through my complex description. You code worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

you can use a sub query to select the values in table b to compare to the column in table A:

```
select * from tableA
Where column1 = 'foo'
and column2 in (select disitnct column8 from tableB where xxxxxxxxx)
```

Comment: You can format your code by selecting and pressing the `{}` button.

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A 
LEFT JOIN TABLE_B 
USING(COLUMN TO MATCH ON)
WHERE TABLE_A.column_1 LIKE 'foo' 
AND  TABLE_B.column_8 LIKE 'bar';
```

I'm not entirely clear what you are actually trying to do so that's probably not the exact code you need.

Comment: Thanks! I completely forgot about that :)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM TABLE_A
    INNER JOIN TABLE_B ON TABLE_A.COLUMN_1 = 'foo' AND TABLE_A.COLUMN_2 = 'bar' AND TABLE_B.COLUMN_8 = 'bar'

This would work on SQL server, probably is the same on MySQL.  Try it!
You can use more than one criterion on a join.